# How can I make directional movement in pygame smooth?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in pygame where you are a jellyfish and you can swim around. I've managed to being able to turn and go in the direction the jellyfish is rotated towards. But when I go in that direction the player image is shaking. Can I fix this somehow?

[image]

Where self.list[int(self.current)] is the current image of the animation and dt delta time.

```
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]:
    self.rotr = math.radians(self.rot)
    self.ysp = math.cos(self.rotr)
    self.xsp = math.sin(self.rotr)
    self.x -= self.xsp*dt*20
    self.y -= self.ysp*dt*20
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.list[int(self.current)], self.rot)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))

if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    self.rot += math.pi*dt*7

if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    self.rot -= math.pi*dt*7
```

Comment: Seems that you're relying on some kind of quantized (i.e. integer) value for the position and/or rotation. You should be using X and Y values, and angle values, that are floats. But without a [mre] this question is impossible to answer and will probably be closed. But anyway, it's common for people to use image pixel values or rect X and Y values as coordinates for their objects, which introduces all kinds of jitter like you're experiencing. You need to round the floating point X and Y values in order to put the sprite somewhere on the screen.

Comment: I can't tell what you mean by "shaking".  It doesn't look bad to me.  You do get some artifacts because of the image rotation, but that's always going to be true when rotating a small image with sharp edges.  You might think about changing your jellyfish to have softer edges.

Comment: Sorry for not adding my code but I did that now. Atleast the code that I think matters

Comment: Try `self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(x), round(y)))`. In Pygame, however, the sprite always moves in septs of 1 pixel. It probably doesn't get any better than that.

Comment: Are the animation sprites all the same size?

Comment: Yes, but thanks for the idea. If I remove the animation the problem still persists

Comment: So it probably doesn't get any better if you use pygame.

Answer (score 0):

You may have seen tutorials for how to move objects in PyGame, which rely on integer X and Y values. This is not a great way to achieve smooth motion. An example of **NOT** smooth motion is below - notice how the velocity and position values are integers:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()  
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Moving rectangle")
x = 200 #integer value
y = 200 #integer value
width = 20
height = 20
vel = 10 # integer value
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    #int values are directly used for screen position
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height)) 
    pygame.display.update() 
pygame.quit()
```

This is a simple fix, though:

```
x = 200.0 #now a float
y = 200.0 #now a float
width = 20
height = 20
vel = 10.0 #now a float
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    #now converting X and Y from floats to integers, rounding first
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (int(round(x)), int(round(y)), width, height))
```

Notice how when we draw the rect, we round the X and Y coordinates. The rounded coordinates are the display coordinates. Your X and Y values that you use internally don't even have to correspond to pixel values 1:1; you're in control of how the conversion from position coordinates to screen coordinates happens. This is just the simplest case.

Even smoother motion can be achieved using acceleration, friction, etc. There are many tutorials on that though.